# Remove Function - Array Based List

Tags: c++, arraylist

I have an array-based list class called Alist with the following remove function. Note that everything is done with respect to the fence, so removing item is done to the right of the fence. This means if I want to delete a specific item, I should set the value of fence to the index of that item, then call the remove function.

```
template <class Elem>
bool AList<Elem>::remove(Elem& item) 
{
    if (rightLength() == 0) return false;

    it = listArray[fence + 1]; // Copy element

    for (int i = fence + 1; i < listSize; i++)
    {
        listArray[i] = listArray[i + 1]; 
    }

    listSize--;
    return true;
```

Now I have created a list of majors and have implemented the following function:

```
void removeMajor(AList<Major> &t, Major &m)
{
   if (t.find(m))
   {
       t.setPos() // ??? Not sure 
       t.remove(m); //inserting major
   }
}
```

My removeMajor function is wrong, I don't know how to set the position of the fence to the element I want to delete. Could anyone help me?

Side Note: (setPos() function is as follows)

```
bool setPos(int pos)
{
    if ((pos >= 0) && (pos < listSize))
        fence = pos;
    return (pos >= 0) && (pos < listSize);
}
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your `remove()` member function does not even use its `item` argument... Why don't you just take the position as an input instead of a "fence" member variable? (Or better yet, accept an iterator...)

Comment: The remove function has an argument as courtesy of the coder to the person interacting with the list. It returns the element to be deleted, that is why is it passed by reference.

Comment: But your code now does not touch it...

Have you looked at the C++ standard library `<algorithm>` header? It has a lot of functions for this sort of thing already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a function, `find`:

```
template <class Elem>
int AList<Elem>::find(Elem& item) 
{
   for (int i = fence + 1; i <= listSize; i++)
   {
      if ( listArray[i] == item )
      {
         return i;
      }
   }

   return -1;
}
```

and then, using it in the implementation of `remove`.

```
template <class Elem>
bool AList<Elem>::remove(Elem& item) 
{
   int index = this->find(item);
   if ( index == -1 )
   {
      return false;
   }

    for (int i = index; i <= listSize; i++)
    {
        listArray[i] = listArray[i + 1]; 
    }

    listSize--;
    return true;
}
```

In both the functions, I am using `i <= listSize` since you have the "fence" item.

Please note that if there are multiple items that are equal to `item`, the function will remove only the first one. You'll have to make sure that rest of your code does not have a problem with that behavior.